# Parsec output on unicode (UTF-8) char

Tags: haskell, unicode, utf-8, char, parsec

Just need to understand something related to Parsec.

```
parseTest (many1 alphaNum) "re2re1Δ"
"re2re1\916"
:t parseTest (many1 alphaNum) 
parseTest (many1 alphaNum) :: Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream s Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Char =>
 s -> IO ()
```

So, the output of the Unicode (should be UTF-8, since I am on OSX) is printed as the hex (?) code (should be the greek delta character).
Now, the putChar does not make the same conversion inside the same ghci session (and the same terminal)

```
Text.Parsec.Char> putChar 'Δ'
Δ
```

How come? They should both be just 'Char' types somehow...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason here has got to do with the way `show` and `putChar` are implemented.

```
λ> show "re2re1Δ"
"\"re2re1\\916\""
λ> mapM_ putChar "re2re1Δ"
re2re1Δ
```

From the source you can see that `Show` instance for `Char` is defined like this:

```
instance  Show Char  where
    showsPrec _ '\'' = showString "'\\''"
    showsPrec _ c    = showChar '\'' . showLitChar c . showChar '\''

    showList cs = showChar '"' . showl cs
                 where showl ""       s = showChar '"' s
                       showl ('"':xs) s = showString "\\\"" (showl xs s)
                       showl (x:xs)   s = showLitChar x (showl xs s)
```

`putChar` is implemented like this:

```
putChar         :: Char -> IO ()
putChar c       =  hPutChar stdout c
```

The `parseTest` function is internally using the `print` function which itself internally uses `show` and that's why you are getting the Unicode codepoint value for delta.